# How to create CPointer of primitive data type in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, cinterop

Allocating and obtaining a pointer of a struct is quite simple:

```kotlin
memScoped {
    val str: StructType = alloc<StructType>()
    val strPtr: CPointer<StructType> = str.ptr
}
```

But I'm struggling to allocate or get pointer of the `Int`, `UInt`, `Long`, `ULong` and other primitive data types.

[image]

Neither there is any extension to these types:

```kotlin
val intData = 5
intData.ptr  // <-- no extension like that
```

Searched a lot, but there seems no documentation for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Replace `Int`, `Long` etc with `IntVar`, `LongVar` etc. See e.g. https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2019/01/14/kn-intptr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael is totally correct, Kotlin primitive types are not supposed to work like that. As explained in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html#basic-interop-types), one should use special types representing lvalues in such cases. Something like this should work:

```kotlin
memScoped {
    val i = alloc<IntVar>()
    i.value = 5
    val p = i.ptr
}
```